# How do I tell gradle run to use a custom working directory?

Tags: java, gradle

I'd like to execute a java class with `gradle run` with a custom working directory. From my reading of the docs simply doing `gradle run -PworkingDir=<mydir>` should do the trick, but it doesn't work the working dir is still the project dir.

I am using `gradle run` as a part of simple testing script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Need a simple way to set working directory for Run and Debug](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/issues/60):

> It is technically possible to do this by creating a custom `run` task like this:
>
> ```
> task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
>     main = project.hasProperty('mainClass') ? project.mainClass : ''
>     classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
>     standardInput = System.in
>
>     if (project.hasProperty('runWorkingDir')) {
>         workingDir = new File(project.runWorkingDir)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In this case you can specify a `-PrunWorkingDir=<my-working-dir>`. The obvious caveat of this is that you have to do this for debug as well and you may have to specify the working directory again for "Run Single" and "Debug Single" as well.
>
> However, instead of adding a project property for working directory, I'm thinking allowing adding a set of variables. This case you only have to specify the working directory once and then you only need to write "-PrunWorkingDir=${run-working-dir}". Also, the built-in run task could support the "runWorkingDir" property.